# How to resolve hibernate table creation while its says unsuccessful creating table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring

I have a domain class name DataList

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "list_data")
public class ListData {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;
@Column(name = "sys_id")
private String sysId;
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
@Column(name = "detail")
private String detail;
@Column(name = "values")
private String values;

   //getters and setters
  }
```

I have some others domain class.. 
I'm using hibernate 3.6 everything alright.

but somehow Im unsuccessful while creating this table.

> 2012-02-25 03:31:52,166 ERROR SchemaExport:274 Unsuccessful: create table list_data (id >integer not null auto_increment, detail varchar(255), name varchar(255), sys_id varchar(255), >values varchar(255), primary key (id)) 
>   2012-02-25 03:31:52,167 ERROR SchemaExport:275 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the >manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values >varchar(255), primary key (id))' at line 1

I know my hibernate configuration is fine, I have some other domain class, they are working just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you cannot use `values` as a column name since it is a MySQL keyword (INSERT INTO ... VALUES() ).

Comment: That would be my guess as well. In general when I use hibernate I label columns with f_ and tables with t_ to avoid reserved names issues.